# Android ant script workaround?

Tags: android, ant, build-process

It appears that, in the transition between the Android 1.1 sdk and 1.5, Google radically changed how ant scripts using AAPT can build Android projects.  Previously they support args allowing developers to specify source, res, asset, and a manifest for a particular build.
Now, they seem to allow developers to specify only a single folder containing everything.  While I could rewrite all our build scripts to work in this new way, I rather like our current system (as it doesn't require more hours of work that I don't have).  To that end, has anyone figured out how to go back to the pre 1.5 method of ant script building? Further, has anyone found a rational reason for this change?

Answer (score 0):

use google there are already pre-written ant build scripts for android 1.5 if all else fails look up an android project on google code and browse svn to get a copy oof their build script..

Comment: I know I can build using the google way, but google has changed it's build process and I don't want to rewrite my builds scripts